# How to make this image responsive while retaining its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

I am currently working on a website design using HTML and CSS and I want to position [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGDym.png) to fit in the page like this:

[image: Mockup Design I made.]

I need it to be responsive.

What I did for its part is:

HTML:

```html
<div class="intro">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGDym.png" class="sensei-img">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.intro {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: overlay;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.intro .sensei-img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5vw;
  bottom: -10vh;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I can position the image perfectly with `position:absolute;` but I can't seem to be able to make it's size responsive (I want it to retain its ratio even if the viewport changes). What should I do?

Comment: "Responsive" just means "Adapts to fit the window". You haven't said *how* you want it to adapt.

Comment: I want its size to be responsive and to stay in its ratio even if the viewport changes. Please tell me if I need more explaining.

Comment: When the window is very thin and long (e.g. a portrait mode phone) where do you want to place the image in relation to the text? [and many other questions in relation to font size and small devices and different aspect ratios].

Comment: I actually defined a left and top position in the CSS snippet. Anyway, I don't really mind the positioning. What I want to solve is that when I resize the browser window, the image ratio is ruined. the ratio is supposed to be 2:1 but when I resize the browser window, the image goes out of its ratio.

Comment: Define just whichever one you want - width or height - but not both. I guess you want to keep the height setting - but that depends on what you want to do with different viewport aspect ratios. You might also like to investigate object-fit (or background-size) contain setting.

Comment: Yeah thank you I'm actually a noob in css so I only learned that now hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For its ratio to be kept even if the viewport changes you can simply remove this property:
`.intro .sensei-img {height: 100vh;}`

The image will keep it's aspect ratio by default.

Comment: thanks @Andre removing one of the sizes seemed to work. Although instead of removing the heigth, I had to remove the width in my case. Thanks again!